# Sitemap is missing on Multisite Install. What's wrong?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am currently facing an issue in the WordPress backend. Whenever I install an SEO plugin, the sitemap does not show up. My client has informed me that they have installed a multi-site in the single WordPress. Can you help me understand what this means?

As I am a junior developer for a big company I am under pressure to fix this issue quickly as failing to do so may result in me losing my job. I would appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: [WordPress Multisite: A Complete Guide to Setting Up and Using Multisite](https://wpbuffs.com/wordpress-multisite/) (no affiliation, just the first result that looked sensible)

Comment: Please take the [tour]. This is not a code-writing service. See also [ask]

Comment: The SEO plugins are commercial products with free-tier versions. Therefore you should consult their support teams. It's not possible for internet randos to help you without knowing what plugin etc. Some SEO plugin free tiers don't work with multisite.

Comment: @Ron I don't think the OP is asking for code. Just an explanation on some terms.

Comment: @BlueRobin from [tour] : "Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers.". Maybe you will also benefit from reading these articles.